# Join bounded and non-bounded source, Data Flow job not scaling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Recently, I have started working with Apache Beam and Google's Cloud Data Flow, to develop Big Data
processing pipeline.  I am planning to leverage [Beam's internal stateful processing model](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html), 
to develop my processing pipeline.

Below is gist of what I want to achieve

- Read data from non-bounded (streaming) source, for GCP this would be PubSub.  Transform the data into KV
- Read data from bounded source, for GCP my case this would be GCS. Transform the data into KV
- As one of the source is non-bounded, I have to do Window and Triggering. I am choosing to use Global Window, as I want to join data coming from the non-bounded source to the bounded source if it already exists in my internal state management.
- Join data from PubSub and GCS, on common key.
- Add data to Beam's internal state, using [Beam's BagState](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/BagState.html) (StateId and StateSpec).  Emit the Iterable of data added to BagState.  Flatten Iterable, and write the emitted PCollection to GCS
- Perform some ParDo(function), on iterable of data.  Write the emitted PCollection to GCS

Below is a sample code snippet

```
public static PipelineResult run(BeamStateFullProcessingPoC.Options options) {

    // User - Think of it as Java POJO / Avro record / Protobuf message.

    // create the pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    /**
    *   Step - 1
    *   Read data from non-bounded (streaming) source, for GCP this would be PubSub.  
    *   Transform the data into KV<String, Object>
    */
    final PCollection<PubsubMessage> pubsubEvents = ... 
    final PCollection<KV<String, User>> pubSubUserByUserId = ...

    /**
    *   Step - 2
    *   Read data from bounded source, for GCP my case this would be GCS. 
    *   Transform the data into KV<String, Object>
    */
    final PCollection<User> users = ...
    final PCollection<KV<String, User>> gcsUserByUserId = ...

    List<PCollection<KV<String, User>>> pCollectionList = new ArrayList<>();
    pCollectionList.add(pubSubUserByUserId);
    pCollectionList.add(gcsUserByUserId);

    PCollection<KV<String, User>> allKVData = PCollectionList
                  .of(pCollectionList)
                  .apply("flatten KV ID with User", Flatten.pCollections());


    /**
    *   Step - 3 
    *   Perform Window + Triggering and GroupByKey
    *   As one of the Source is streaming, we need to do Window and trigger, before grouping by key
    */
    final PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<User>>> iterableUserByIdKV = allKVData
            .apply("batch data by window + trigger",
                    Window.<KV<String, User>> into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
    .apply("GroupByKey per User", GroupByKey.create());

    /**
    *   Step - 4
    *   Add User to Beam's internal state, using Beam's BagState (StateId and StateSpec)
    *   Emit the Iterable<User> added to BagState
    *   Flatten Iterable, and write the emitted PCollection to GCS
    */    
    final PCollection<Iterable<User>> iterableUser = iterableUserByIdKV
            .apply("User added to State by Key", ParDo.of(new CreateInternalStateDoFn()));

    final PCollection<User> userAddedToState = iterableUser
            .apply("flatten userAddedToState", Flatten.iterables());
    userAddedToState.apply("write userAddedToState", AvroIO.write(User.class)
            .to(options.getOutputDirectoryForUserState())
            .withSuffix(".avro")
            .withWindowedWrites()
            .withNumShards(options.getNumShards()));


    /**
    *   Step - 5
    *   Perform some function via ParDo on Iterable<User> 
    *   Write emitted data to GCS
    */
    final PCollection<User> changeGenderUser = iterableUser
            .apply("DetectChangeGenderDoFn", ParDo.of(new DetectChangeGenderDoFn()));

    changeGenderUser.apply("write change gender", AvroIO.write(User.class)
            .to(options.getOutputDirectoryForChangeGender())
            .withSuffix(".avro")
            .withWindowedWrites()
            .withNumShards(options.getNumShards()));

    return pipeline.run();
}
```

Below is JSON paylod to create Data Flow Template Job

```
{
  "jobName": "poc-beam-state-management",
  "parameters": {
    "personSubscription": "projects/<project-name>/subscriptions/<subscription-name>",
    "locationForUser": "gs://<bucket>/<user-folder>/*.avro",
    "outputDirectoryForChangeGender": "gs://<bucket>/<folder>/",
    "outputDirectoryForUserState": "gs://<bucket>/<folder>/",
    "avroTempDirectory": "gs://<bucket>/<folder>/",
    "numShards": "5",
    "autoscalingAlgorithm": "THROUGHPUT_BASED",
    "numWorkers": "3",
    "maxNumWorkers": "18"    
  },
  "environment": {
    "subnetwork": "<some-subnet>",
    "zone": "<some-zone>",
    "serviceAccountEmail": "<some-service-account>",
  },
  "gcsPath": "gs://<bucket>/<folder>/templates/<TemplateName>"
}
```

When my Data Flow job starts, it is only performing the work on 1 Worker node.
I am under the assumption, that Google Cloud Platform, Data Flow will automagically scale the job with Worker nodes, as needed.

Q: How can Data Flow job, auto scale and leverage GCP capability of performing work in distributed fashion?

[Data Flow Job DAG (sub-part-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfVgD.png)
[Data Flow Job DAG (sub-part-2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RIoV.png)

Answer (score 0):

So your base assumption in the list you provided above has some flaws. You state that ***As one of the source is non-bounded... I am choosing to use Global Window, as I want to join data coming from the non-bounded source to the bounded source...emphasized text***

In Beam, you can not perform a global window on an infinite stream since you can not fit the stream into memory. You would need to fit them into fixed windows which you can read [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-basics). Because of the global window the job would not never complete.

Secondly, if you are running a Dataflow streaming job then google defaults the job to `autoscalingAlgorithm=NONE`. You would want to specify it to `autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED`. You can find details [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params) that explain it better. This prevents your machine from autoscaling.

Hope this provides the answer you were looking for.